# How to append extra column with default value in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tweepy, twitterapi-python

How do i append extra column with default value in pandas dataframe ?

please refer the code below :

```
userID = "narendramodi"
tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=userID, 
                           # 200 is the maximum allowed count
                           count=500,
                           include_rts = True,
                           # Necessary to keep full_text 
                           # otherwise only the first 140 words are extracted
                           tweet_mode = 'extended'
                           )

all_tweets = []
all_tweets.extend(tweets)
oldest_id = tweets[-1].id
while True:
    tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=userID, 
                           # 200 is the maximum allowed count
                           count=200,
                           include_rts = True,
                           max_id = oldest_id - 1,
                           # Necessary to keep full_text 
                           # otherwise only the first 140 words are extracted
                           tweet_mode = 'extended'
                           )
    if len(tweets) == 0:
        break
    oldest_id = tweets[-1].id
    all_tweets.extend(tweets)
    print('N of tweets downloaded till now {}'.format(len(all_tweets)))


from pandas import DataFrame
outtweets = [[
              
              tweet.id_str, 
              tweet.created_at, 
              tweet.favorite_count, 
              tweet.retweet_count,]  for idx,tweet in enumerate(all_tweets)]

df = DataFrame(outtweets,columns=["id",
                                  "created_at",
                                  "favorite_count",
                                  "retweet_count",)]
df.head(10)
```

Please refer the below code, it runs okay but i want to add the extra column in dataframe. suppose default value as **domain = "NA"** for all tweets reflecting in dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as simple as:

```py
df['domain'] = "NA"
```

Comment: this will only work for one element but i want it for all the tweets appearing in df, what should write in outtweets =[ ]

Comment: The line I mentioned, right before `df.head(10)` does the job.

Comment: The other option is to add "NA" in the comprehensive list creation: `...tweet.retweet_count, "NA"]` and the column name in the dataframe construction: `..."retweet_count", "domain"]`

Answer (score 0):

It'll fill new_col with NaN values.

```
import numpy as np

df['new_col'] = np.NaN
```

Comment: this will only work for one element but i want it for all the tweets appearing in df, what should write in outtweets =[ ]